# How to Convert Curl to PHP

Tags: php, curl, asp.net-web-api

I am having a problem with my php script.

When i run this command in terminal :-

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Futuresimple-Token:mytoken" \
-H "Accept:application/xml" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
--data "{\"lead\" : { \"company_name\" : \"Cody Test\", \
  \"first_name\" : \"Cody\", \"last_name\" : \"Guest\", \"email\" : \"Cody.guest@boxview.com\" }}" \
  https://leads.futuresimple.com/api/v1/leads.json
```

It works. But i want to convert it into PHP so that i can get the response using PHP

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php. You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Slap on the "--libcurl example.c" option to get your program in plain C, from there it is usually easy to make it into PHP...

Comment: Can you please provide an example what it is sending to the URL ? I am a newbie :(

Comment: What do you mean? Your question contains a full example and if you use --libcurl as I mentioned you'll see how the libcurl-using code would look like. The URL in there is where the POST is sent, the --data is a string you pass to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: <?php
$lead = array(
'lead' => array(
'company_name' => 'ASDF, Inc.',
'last_name'    => 'Guest',
'first_name'   => 'Cody'
) 
);
$test = http_build_query($lead);
echo $test;
$authHeader = 'X-Futuresimple-Token:token';

//print_r($lead["lead"]["company_name"]);
$ch = curl_init('http://leads.futuresimple.local/api/v1/leads.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($lead));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authHeader));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
?>

Comment: Using the above code but still not working like it works in the terminal(Ubuntu) :(